# document.ready in external js files which detect which file is load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file structure with multiple html files. Each file has an include to the same js file. Some code intends only for the index.html in the document.ready function, and some other only maybe for the help.html. So here is my question:

Is there a clean solution to run only the needed code snippets for the index.html in the document.ready function(which is defined in the ext js file) if I access the index.html(same for help.html?

**Note**: I want to store all JS-Code in the external js. I know, I could store the needed code snippets in the header of each file, but i really want to store the whole js code only in one ext file.

Comment: so, what's wrong with checking `window.location.href` and executing those snippets according to which page is showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options

1) You can interrogate the url `document.URL` and determine if it matches what you want, and execute that in an if block.  e.g.

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
};

if (document.URL.endsWith('testDir/index.html')) {
    //do logic.
}
```

2) You could also put a special div id/class/etc on your index

```
<div id='divImInIndex'></div>

if ($('#divImInIndex').length > 0) {
    //do logic
}
```

There may be other methods... but this definitely doesn't follow best practices.  I believe of the two I've presented, #2 is the better option simply because you're not sure if url-rewriting has occurred, or if a default document was loaded by the server (e.g. the url could be `/testDir/` so the server provides `/testDir/index.html`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have got a function like the #1, but the #2 idea is also for me the better choice, cause as you said, in future i want to use url-rewriting rules.